# NIntegrate converging too slowly when increasing size of array

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a problem with a numerical integration. I have a 4x4x4x4 array that has for each entry an integral and I want to use `NIntegrate` to evaluate it. It gives me no problem, it's actually pretty fast. But if I increase the size of the array to 9x9x9x9 I get this message:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
>   suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is
>   0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

I increased the working precision already but it didn't help.

**EDITED:**

I put here a simplified version of my code:

```
B9b = Array[Nspher[#2, #4] &, {9, 9, 9, 9}, {1, 0, 1, 0}]
```

where

```
Nspher[l_, k_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  SphericalHarmonicY[l, 0, θ, φ] SphericalHarmonicY[k, 0, θ, φ]*Sin[θ],
  {θ, 0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π},
  WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 30]
```

Comment: Hmm, oscillatory and finite... try setting `Method -> "ClenshawCurtisOscillatoryRule"`.

Comment: @0x4A4D It didn't work

Comment: I still do not understand why it works if the array is smaller and it doesn't if I
 increase the size.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? "Didn't work" tells me absolutely nothing on what might have gone wrong. Unless your actual integral does not in fact involve `SphericalHarmonicY[]`...

Comment: I meant I get the same error message, `NIntegrate::slwcon:`. And now I'm evaluating exactly what I posted here.

Comment: As a matter of course, it might interest you to know that `SphericalHarmonicY[k, 0, θ, ϕ]` is **independent of `ϕ`**, so you can certainly rewrite your multiple integral as a one-dimensional integral...

Comment: @0x4A4D I know, I put zero here but later I will need also other m values.

Comment: Even so, you still have a *separable integral*; you can set things up so you have the product of two one-dimensional integrals, and that is a considerably easier task than multiple integration.

Comment: you're right, thanks for the tip

Comment: Try this for your argument to `Array` and see if you can figure out why the change in array size makes a difference: `Check[Nspher[#2, #4], Print[{#2, #4}]] &`

Comment: Also in the simplified example, you're computing the integral for each `k`, `l` 81 times and `NSphere` is symmetric in `k`, `l`.  That must take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code seems to repeatedly evaluate the same integral many times. To see this, try changing `Nspher` as follows:

```
Nspher[l_, k_] := (Print[{l, k}]; 
  NIntegrate[
   SphericalHarmonicY[l, 0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] SphericalHarmonicY[k, 
     0, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 
    0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 30])
```

To fix it, use memoization:

```
Nspher[l_, k_] := 
 Nspher[l, k] = (Print[{l, k}]; 
   NIntegrate[
    SphericalHarmonicY[l, 0, \[Theta], \[Phi]] SphericalHarmonicY[k, 
      0, \[Theta], \[Phi]]*Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 
     0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 30])
```

As for `NIntegrate::slwcon`, *this message does not necessarily indicate an error*. It is simply a report that the error estimate on a sub-region did not decrease as fast as it is expected to (eventually) decrease, assuming the function is nicely behaved. This can be a hint that better methods or other special handling can help you. If no other messages ensue, the result of NIntegrate is still likely to be good.

Using something like the above code, you can find out all/some of the specific values of {l, k} for which your computation is producing slwcon. For example, {l, k} == {2, 8} is one case. Investigate these, and once you are satisfied, you could Quiet slwcon or solve those cases in some other way.